# how to include PHP script as body of email

Tags: php, html, email, joomla, include

I have a php script that makes some MySQL queries that just writes some HTML (with the dynamic data) to a page.  What I want to do is send an email with this HTML as the body.  Lets say that the HTML code that I want to insert into the body of the email is contained in `my_html_script.php`, and I want to send it 2 `$_GET` parameters as well to make the dynamic content come out correctly.

I am in the Joomla framework, so the code to send the email looks like this:

```
$mailer =& JFactory::getMailer();
$sender = $from_email;
$mailer->setSender($sender);

$email = explode(';',$email);
for ($i=0;$i<count($email);$i++){
    $mailer->addRecipient(trim($email[$i]));
}

$body   = "




";


$mailer->setSubject('This is the subject');
$mailer->setBody($body);

// Optional file attached
//$mailer->addAttachment();

$send =& $mailer->Send();
if ( $send !== true ) {
    //die($send->message);
    echo "<p>email FAILED".$recip."</p>";
} else {
    //mail sent
    echo "Emailed successfully.";
}
```

So, basically I need to include the HTML output of `my_html_script.php` into the `$body` string variable.  How do I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Three words for your Google search: `php output buffering`. You can (if you must) set the necessary values in `$_GET` before calling `include` - but it would be far better to modify `my_html_script.php` to only use the values from `$_GET` if the values are not inherited in other variables from the parent script.

Comment: @DaveRandom thanks for the tips.  I have the output buffering working.  Unfortunately non of the MySQL data in `my_html_script.php` is being inserted into the HTML, even though there are no errors thrown... :-/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would just declare the variables before this block and use:

```
ob_start();
include ('my_html_script.php');
$body = ob_get_clean();
```

Comment: @Moak Yes it does. Read the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php).

Answer (score 3):

You could do this:

```
$body = file_get_contents("http://example.com/my_html_script.php?getvar=foo&othervar=bar");
```

Comment: Really, you're recommending that? Alright, but I'd expect better from a respected 40K-er such as your good self... (I didn't downvote)

Comment: Yes, why is this not a good idea? It does exactly what the user wants.

Comment: performance wise this can not be better than using a direct include with output buffer

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this, but...

```
$body = file_get_contents("path_to_file.php?param1=content&param2=content");
```

You can send http request with params: param1, param2 or any other.

Answer (score 0):

```
$filename_xml="E-factuur ".$factuurnummer.".xml";
ob_start();
$_GET['knr']=$klantnummer;
$_GET['bnr']=$bestelnummer;
$_GET['key']=$_SESSION['user_id'];
include("basisUBL_xml.php");//inside the above $_GET['..'] are parsed 
$content_xml = ob_get_clean();
$content_xml = chunk_split(base64_encode($content_xml));
$name_xml = basename($filename_xml);
$uid="=_Part_2408_".md5(uniqid(time()));
$logopad_emails="https://www.yourdomainhere.nl/images/logo.png";
$headerx="MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headerx.="From: webshop www.yourdomainhere.nl <info@yourdomainhere.nl>\r\n";
$headerx.="Reply-To: info@yourdomainhere.nl \r\n";
$headerx.="Errors-To: info@yourdomainhere.nl \r\n";
$headerx.="X-Mailer: yourdomainhere Mailscript \r\n";
$headerx.="Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";
// message & attachment
$messagex = "--".$uid."\r\n";
$messagex .= "Content-type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n\r\n"; //2x \r\n important for OXS email and iphone!!!
$messagex .= $htmlbody3."\r\n\r\n";
$messagex .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
$messagex .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$name_pdf."\"\r\n";
$messagex .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
$messagex .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$name_pdf."\"\r\n\r\n";
$messagex .= $content_pdf."\r\n\r\n";
$messagex .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
$messagex .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$name_xml."\"\r\n";
$messagex .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
$messagex .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$name_xml."\"\r\n\r\n";
$messagex .= $content_xml."\r\n\r\n";
$messagex .= "--".$uid."--";
$mailtox='info@yourdomainhere.nl';
$subjectx='UBL test'.$factuurnummer;
```